# How can I make an IK leg rig with a retractable foot part?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

[image: The figure presents the expected behaviour of the rig.]

Hello.
I want to make an IK leg rig. The green part is hidden in the blue part. But I want to be able to come out. Normally the end of the blue part is the last chain of the IK and the part touching the ground, but when the green one came out I want to IK system to behave as the last chain is the green part and green part is touching the ground.
I hope this makes sense.
I tried to learn how to rig a telescopic piston thing but couldn't implement it to this one.
Also couldn't come up with any other thing that works.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think found a solution that does the job.

Extruded: [image]
Collapsed: [image]

The idea is:

[image]

The leg consists of two bones. One dummy bone and one bone where the mesh is assigned to. The Dummy bone also does the job of the ik. Its extruded from the bone above and always has an IK bone onto it. Do dissable it, I scale it down, so its IK solving is being done at the end of the parent position, action like the IK would be on the parent. The One Problem with this, is that the mesh would be also scaled. For this we have the other bone (Not Dummy). This bone has a copy location constraint to dummy bone, so it doesn't get scaled and moves inside the parent bone. It also has two track two modifiers to get the correct rotation. The one Track to is linked to the parent and the other to the dummy.
The Scale and both of the track to constraints are controlled by a custom property and packed in a driver, so you can change all bones by one value.
[image]

Iv'e uploaded the blend file so it's maybe easier to understand.
https://www.file-upload.net/download-15018890/BonesTest.blend.html

Hope I could help (:

Comment: Hey. That's great. It's exactly the thing I am trying to achieve. I should learn more about drivers and constraints because I got confused trying to accomplish a similar rig.
You're great. Thank you very much for your contribution.
Best...